# How can I copy SMSes from Nokia N8 to Android for free?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sms, data-transfer

How can I copy SMSes from Nokia N8 (Symbian) to Android for free ? It is for my very important. I have found MobileTrans application, but it is paid and I wanna not pay 39 $.

Thanks in advance !

***SOLVED***

I solved my problem my exporting SMS to CSV by Nokia Suite and then importing it to my device using SMS Tools - All in One  application.

Comment: There are some similar previous questions about transferring SMS messages from Nokia phones, have you looked at those? [Import SMSes from Nokia 6300](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27153/) / [Transferring messages to android from a sqlite db on my laptop](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25213/) / [SMS backup in Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/9434/156)

Comment: Thanks that you also shared your answer! Would you mind copying that into the answer part (see below), and then accept it?

Comment: Yep, please share your solution as answer and not as edit to your question :)

Answer (score 2):

<sup>As the OP found a solution, but missed to make it an answer, let me transfer it here:</sup>

I solved my problem exporting SMS to CSV by Nokia Suite and then importing it to my device using SMS Tools - All in One application.

Answer (score 0):

IDK if WP8s have this feature, but is there a way to save your messages to the SIM? That is assuming you'll be keeping the SIM.

Comment: SIM cards have very limited memory so this isn't a great solution.

Comment: Well you might as well try, mightn't you?

Comment: Even if it does work it'll only have like 20 messages though so there's actually not much point in even trying. That's assuming SIMs still have such limited memory, the 20 text limit was normal about a decade ago.

Comment: OK @peanut, don't use that way then!